# Are there any languages with the equivalent of "both" for three items?

Tags: historical-linguistics, cross-linguistic, comparative-linguistics

Referring to [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/22357/equivalent-of-both-when-referring-three-or-more-items) it seems that English does not have the equivalent of "both" for three items. Although it would seem to be a useful word, I am unaware of its existence in any languages. Is there any language that has such a word?

Comment: _Both_ is just a suppletive term for _*all two._ Duals have irregular forms like suppletives more often than plurals, but less often than singulars.

Comment: But there is also a category of *trial* in some languages ...

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't usually mean _three_; it's more a small group vs an unlimited plural. Usually it's called "paucal". And it's normally an inflection, not a suppletive quantifier.

Comment: Hmm.  On the other hand, if there aren't languages with a paucal quantifier (meaning roughly "each member of this small group") then that's an interesting gap.

Answer (score 5):

American Sign Language has this.

*Valli, Clayton & Lucas, Ceil. 1995. Linguistics of American Sign Language: An Introduction. 2nd ed. Washington, DC: Gallaudet University Press. page 101*

Comment: Very interesting - but I can't find the reference in the book you pointed to?

Comment: Top paragraph: "... referring to more than one person could also be signed using a number handshape, so that the pronoun could be glossed as TWO-OF-THEM,  or THREE-OF-THEM, or ..." Or you could try here: http://belindavicars.com/grammar/numerical_pronouns.htm

Answer (score 4):

It appears that Hindi has a generic form that accommodates any number at all.

```
Number Hindi word  Adj
2      do          donõ
3      teen        teenõ
4      chaar       chaarõ
```

However, as the numbers get bigger, it appears<sup>§</sup> to be more idiomatic to switch to a form that's similar to English.

*tum chaarõ ladke mere saath aaoo.*
All four of you boys come with me.

*tum saare chalis ladke mere saath aaoo.*
All forty of you boys come with me.

<sup>§</sup> — I speak the language fluently, but I'm not a native speaker.

Comment: Are you sure it is nasal? Just asking, I am a native speaker, but never actually studied the language, so I am not sure. (Also, I know using the letter 'd' for the retroflex 'r' is a common convention, but it still confuses me.)

Comment: @QuintusCaesius In writing, I have seen both तीनो / तीनों, both चरो / चरों, etc. Even dictionaries use both forms like here: https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/hindi-english/%E0%A4%9A%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%8B%E0%A4%82-%E0%A4%93%E0%A4%B0.

Comment: oh, because normally I don't nasalise that specific suffix when speaking.

Answer (score 3):

**Thai** `ทั้ง` [tʰáŋ] is often used for this purpose.
Also, `กัน` [gan] (one another), e.g. ต่อกัน [tò-gan] (mutually).

I guess, most (if not all) [isolating languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolating_language) would have such a word, and most likely it would be the same as "together", "also", or "one another".

Also, **Hebrew** [has dual and triple inflection forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modern_Hebrew_grammar#Dual) for certain nouns.

Comment: `ทั้ง` is used for exactly three items? Or for "two or more" items?

Comment: "Two or more". To specify a certain number of objects, they say `ทั้งสอง` (all-two), `ทั้งสาม` (all-three), and so on - but almost never in colloquial speak.

Comment: Ah so it's pretty much the same as in English then, rather than a special "trial" word akin to "both". )-:

Comment: As for Hebrew, "both" is just "two of" (שני\שתי), and for three items you just say "three of" (שלושת\שלוש).

Comment: No, Hebrew does not have a triple inflection form. The example given on the page that you link to shows that the triple form is the regular plural form, in contrast to the dual form which is unique.

Answer (score 2):

When I was studying Generalized Quantifier Theory as part of a Formal Semantics class a few years ago in college, this came up. If I recall correctly, the professor said that there weren't any languages which had a quantifier that had an identical meaning to both, but for the number 3. I don't think there was any real backing up of that assertion.

Certainly there are no major languages that I know of that have this property.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. In Georgian (ქართული) language the word "both" is derived from the word "two" and you can do the same for all numbers, as well as for three.

Answer (score 1):

In Pashto, **درې واړه** [ˈd̪reˑ.wɑ̟̈ɳə] exactly means ‘both for three items’. (It can be used for both humans and inanimate objects.)

Answer (score 0):

The common form in Spanish is *los dos*.  (*Ambos* is a bit formal.)

You can just as easily say *los tres*.

And there are many sayings, songs, soap operas and even hotel names with *felices los quatro*.

[image: Mily Jaramillo - Felices los cuatro (Video Oficial)]

Comment: Looks like a parallel to the English phrasing "the two", not "both".

Comment: @OmarL Looks can be deceiving.  The English phrase *the two* is not and cannot be used in the way that *los dos* most commonly is.

Comment: As the first comment under the question states, the most equivalent English phrase is *all two*.